# Git clone a series of branches but not all

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-clone

With this command, it clones all branches and then finally checks out on the specified branch:

```
git clone -b <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
```

With this command, clone only the specified branch:

```
git clone -b <branchname> --single-branch <remote-repo-url>
```

Is there a way to specify a series of branches to clone them, but not having to have all of them?

```
git clone <branchname>, <branchname2>, <branchname3> ??
```

Something similar?

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to realize that, in a way, you don't clone *branches* in the first place.  You clone *commits*.  Git is all about *commits*, so nearly everything you do is all about *commits*.  That said, we *find* commits by branch names—unless you're crazy enough  to use raw hash IDs that is—and `git clone`, once it's done cloning some or all commits, creates *one* branch name, so it "feels like" you're cloning a branch.

Using `--single-branch`, `--depth`, and the newfangled partial clone features is a way of telling your (client) Git *not* to fetch *all* the commits from the repository you're cloning.  (Remember or realize here that `git clone` consists of running `mkdir`, `git init`, `git remote add`, `git fetch`, and so on; it's the `git fetch` step that copies the commits, and the default is to copy *all* commits.<sup>1</sup>)

What you probably want in this case is: *copy all commits, then don't create **any** branch names*.  That is:

```
git clone --no-checkout <url>
```

This way, you'll get all the commits—and remote-tracking names for all of *their* branches—but no *branch names* of your own, and no commit checked out yet.  Now you can enter the new clone and *create* a branch name for each remote-tracking name for each branch name that you want to have:

```
cd new-clone
for b in main feature dev; do git branch --track origin/$b; done
```

Now you *still* have nothing checked out yet, but you have `main`, `feature`, and `dev` all set up with `origin/main`, `origin/feature`, and `origin/dev` as their upstreams, ready to use.

You could also use:

```
git clone <url>
cd new-repo
for b in feature dev; do git checkout $b; done && git checkout main\
```

(assuming that you'd like to have `main` checked out and that this is what `git clone` is going to check out as its last step).  This is *less efficient*, but computer efficiency is often irrelevant here: what's an extra 2 or 3 seconds when your `git clone`'s `git fetch` step takes 50 seconds to retrieve all the commits?

Remember that:

```
git checkout something
```

*means:*

```
git checkout --guess something
```

(unless you turn guessing off).  The same applies to the newfangled `git switch`.  The `--guess` option says: *before you complain that there's no such branch name, go look at my **remote-tracking** names and see if there's exactly one that matches up, and if so, **create** a **new** branch name for me, using the commit specified by that remote-tracking name, and setting up the remote-tracking name as the upstream of my new branch.*<sup>2</sup>

In other words, the default "guess" mode means: *check out the existing branch, or create a new one if you can*.  Since *branch* names don't really matter—except when it comes to finding commits and keeping humans sane—Git can do this for you, as long as you have the right *commits*.  Git only really cares about the *commits*.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, the default is to copy all the commits and tags that have branch or tag or other normally-useful *names* by which they're found.  So `git clone` normally *does not* copy pull request commits on GitHub, which are under a GitHub-specific name-space.  It does *not* copy `refs/replace/` commits from `git replace`, nor commits found only through `refs/stash` or other special names.  But to a first approximation, the default is "get all the commits".  Options like `--single-branch` are there to help avoid this: this is sometimes useful for a very large repository, or one that has huge tarballs committed under specific release names, or whatever.

<sup>2</sup>Whether and when a newly created branch has some upstream pre-set is both configurable and controllable via options like `--track` and `--no-track`; this assumes the usual defaults and commands without options.

Comment: Asp I am a bit lost, let's take example from following repository.
https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker
I just want to have branches, 3.x, 5.x, checkout on 5.x.
How should i do?

Comment: git clone https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker.git

Comment: cd react-native-dropdown-picker

Comment: for b in 3.x 5.x; do git checkout $b; done && git checkout 3.x\

Comment: I get a similar thing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/axPM5.png
But I want in local only 3.x, instead in remote origin I want 3.x and 5.x.
Instead I find myself, in local also dev-5.x and in remote all the branches.

Comment: Your `remotes/origin/*` (use `git branch -a` to see everything at once, then they have `remotes/` in front, or use `git branch -r` to see just the remote-tracking names and then they don't have `remotes/` in front) are just a reflection of the other Git repository's *branch* names. Every time they add a branch name, your next `git fetch` will pick that one up, adding to your `origin/*` collection. Don't worry about these, they're not under your control. You should create and use a *local* name when you want to *make new commits and remember them with a local name*, and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for replying, from what I understand at the moment there is no solution that does what I am looking for.

Comment: You *can* use `git init` followed by `git remote add` with a series of single-branch-clone instructions  (`-t` options) to make an n-branch-clone, then run `git fetch`. There's rarely (so rarely as to claim "never" until you prove otherwise) any reason to bother, though.